# Eevee Render Making Objects Green

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am rendering a laptop animation, and the metal of the laptop is becoming green when I render it via Eevee.
I have tried altering the materials and it has no effect.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1933oUlElwDQBeJQIXqVq3-uWECeHYYiG?usp=sharing. This is a link to download the project folder if anyone wants to help.

All help is appreciate, many thanks.

[image: The first frame]

Comment: Please attach your simplified blend file to see your setup. Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and paste given code into your question. External links aren't allowed here, they aren't permanent.

Comment: @vklidu, would this not remove images? They are in a separate folder. I am using images as well as materials.

Comment: It looks like the reflection of a green environment, are you using an HDRi to light the scene?

Comment: @vklidu, I have uploaded the file to the site, however it is too big. It goes over their 30mb limit. Can you not download the folder from the Drive link?

Comment: @susu I am not. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: https://www.appypie.com/faqs/how-can-i-make-my-google-drive-document-public

Comment: Yes I cant access your file from drive. You don't have to upload such a big file try to delete parts of your scene and upload just a simplified file where issue still resist. By deleting part by part there is a chance you will discover what it cause by your self :)